# Is there any publicly available logging, or "Wayback Machine" for DSN Now activity?

Tags: juno, deep-space-network, historical-data

This [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17045/12102) and especially this [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/#comment43533_17045) address activity associated with the Juno mission, both circa arrival, and the relatively quiet transit period to Jupiter. The idea is that there may have been infrequent contact with Juno, or contact of short duration during transit, but there has probably been quite a burst of activity not that it has arrived.

Now I wish I could see that, or even make a plot of frequency or duration or just some kind of qualitative metric, for general interest, and for future answers in stack exchange.

Is there a way to get statistics or logging information about what has been displayed on the Deep Space Network NOW page? (https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html)

Certainly some kind of log of what information was sent to the server that generates the page exists. I'm not looking for actual communications logs, just a way to summarize or histogram activity as displayed on the web page.

Any idea how to do this? Is there a way or a place to suggest this? I know the chances are low that anyone would have to the time to do this, but there may be a "feature request" feature somewhere. Also, it's possible someone is already doing this and doesn't know that anyone else is interested.

Comment: Actually, you could consider emailing them at dsnnow@jpl.nasa.gov.  They're fairly responsive; they replied last time I emailed them.  I'll ask around at JPL while I'm here to see if I can find anything out as well.

Comment: @uhoh See my answer [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28401/) for complete data from Jan 1, 2010, till Sep 1, 2018

Comment: @MarkOmo fantastic!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have been looking into this as well. As I have been told by one NASA employee, there is no *easy* way to get old data, but there is a way if you're willing to go through lots of data. NASA saves old `dsn.xml` files in an address like so:

http://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/data/1365107113.xml

That number is a unix timestamp, so that you can view the XML data at that time. For a unix to date convert, try e.g. https://www.epochconverter.com

The data are stored only every five seconds, so if one unix timestamp gives you a "NoSuchKey" error, try to keep going down by one until you find a good one.

Comment: That's excellent!! Yep the time of the 5-second sampling has a 'phase drift' but plenty of data there. Using python; `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30923963/3904031), this one line returns a dictionary that can be reduced, or saved as a json; `DSNdict = dictify(ET.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()))` Thanks!

Comment: These XML's, what do they contain?