# Understanding the information contained in the Deep Space Network XML data?

Tags: nasa, deep-space, deep-space-network

NASA's Deep Space Network activity can be viewed conveniently at https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html but if you would like data in a more raw XML form, it can be accessed as described in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20889/12102)

Below is a small Python script that reads the XML into a list of dictionaries, and saves it to disk as a JSON.

The dictionaries are organized at the higher level by dish, then by spacecraft per dish.

**Question:** What are the most-likely meanings of all the data field contained in the Deep Space Network XML data?

This is the example url from the other answer, used in the script below: https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/data/1365107113.xml

```
def dictify(r,root=True): # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python/30923963#30923963
    if root:
        return {r.tag : dictify(r, False)}
    d=copy(r.attrib)
    if r.text:
        d["_text"]=r.text
    for x in r.findall("./*"):
        if x.tag not in d:
            d[x.tag]=[]
        d[x.tag].append(dictify(x,False))
    return d

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from copy import copy
import requests, json, pprint

# https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/dsnnow/
# https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html
# https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17046/is-there-any-publicly-available-logging-or-wayback-machine-for-dsn-now-activi

N     = 1365107113

url   = "https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/data/" + str(N) + ".xml"

r     = requests.get(url)

text  = r.text

a     = ET.fromstring(text)

things = [dictify(x) for x in a]

with open (str(N) + '_XML', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(things, outfile)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=1)

for i, thing in enumerate(things):
    print "i = ", i
    pp.pprint(thing)
```

Here are the last two "things" this prints:

```
i =  14
{'dish': {'_text': '\n\t\t',
          'azimuthAngle': '16.999969',
          'created': '2013-04-04T07:00:42.036Z',
          'downSignal': [{'dataRate': '2291.963470',
                          'frequency': '8445767679.000001',
                          'power': '-482.579407',
                          'signalType': 'none',
                          'signalTypeDebug': 'IDLE OFF 0 MCD2',
                          'spacecraft': 'RSTS',
                          'spacecraftId': '99'}],
          'elevationAngle': '88.000488',
          'isArray': 'false',
          'isDDOR': 'false',
          'isMSPA': 'false',
          'name': 'DSS43',
          'target': [{'downlegRange': '-1.0',
                      'id': '99',
                      'name': 'RSTS',
                      'rtlt': '-1.0',
                      'uplegRange': '-1.0'}],
          'upSignal': [{'dataRate': '',
                        'frequency': '',
                        'power': '',
                        'signalType': 'none',
                        'signalTypeDebug': '  ',
                        'spacecraft': 'RSTS',
                        'spacecraftId': '99'}],
          'updated': '2013-04-04T07:00:42.036Z',
          'windSpeed': '0.000000'}}
i =  15
{'timestamp': {'_text': '1365107113334'}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It took me several days observing data from DSN.  Here is my analysis of the fields from the XML data files.

`station`

- `name`: Call sign for the station.
- `friendlyName`: Common name for the station (Goldstone, Madrid, Canberra).
- `timeUTC`: Time that this report happened, using Coordinated Universal Time, in milliseconds (1/1000 of second) since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (1 January 1970).
- `timeZoneOffset`: Add this number to `timeUTC` to get the local time of this station, again in milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

`dish`

- `name`: Identifier of the dish.  Usually "DSS" followed by two decimal digits.
- `azimuthAngle`, `elevationAngle`: The astronomical azimuth and elevation where this dish is currently pointing, in degrees with a decimal fraction.
- `windSpeed`: The wind speed around the dish, in km/hr.
- `isMSPA`: If "true", the dish is listening to more than one target (Multiple Spacecraft Per Aperture).
- `isArray`: If "true", the dish is part of a dish array.
- `isDDOR`: If "true", the dish is being used for [Delta Differential One-way Ranging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-Differential_One-Way_Ranging).
- `created`, `updated`: File creation and modification times (of what?), in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

`target`

- `name`: The call sign for the target spacecraft.
- `id`: A decimal ID number for each spacecraft.  Appears to be sequentially assigned (starting at 1) when the spacecraft was added to the database.
- `uplegRange`, `downlegRange`: Estimated distance to and from the target, in km.  Should be the same, unless using an array or DDOR.  Seems to be off by a factor of 2.
- `rtlt`: Round-trip light time, in seconds.  Seems to be off by a factor of 2.

`upSignal`

- `signalType`: `none` if setup/teardown/tracking, `carrier` if carrier frequency only, `data` if something actually being sent.
- `signalTypeDebug`: Unknown; intended for the programmers.
- `power`: Power of transmitted signal, in kW.
- `frequency`: Frequency of transmitted signal, in **MHz**.
- `dataRate`: Bits per second of transmitted data.
- `spacecraft`: Call sign of targeted spacecraft.
- `spacecraftId`: ID number of targeted spacecraft.

`downSignal`

- `signalType`: `none` if setup/teardown/tracking, `carrier` if carrier frequency only, `data` if something actually being received.
- `signalTypeDebug`: Unknown; intended for the programmers.
- `spacecraft`: Call sign of targeted spacecraft.
- `spacecraftId`: ID number of targeted spacecraft.
- `dataRate`: Bits per second of received data.
- `frequency`: Frequency of received signal, in **Hz**.  Note the different units and higher precision than the upSignal; this would be useful for analyzing the Doppler effect of the spacecraft's motion.
- `power`: Power of received signal, in [dBm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm).  There have been several times where two targets of the same dish have nearly identical power, except offset by a value of 300: typically -1xx.xx and -4xx.xx dBm.  Therefore, I think 300 is deducted from the power as a flag for a certain condition (which I have yet to identify).  Code to handle this value should look like this:

> ```
> if (power < -300.00)
>    power = power + 300.00
> ```

Please give this a try, plot the results, and *let us know if it works!*

---

You'll notice that units are not consistent.  Time can be in Unix time or in ISO 8601.  Frequency can be in Hz or MHz.  Power can be in kW or dBm.

I would be concerned that units might change in the future, or have changed in the past.  Therefore, I would recommend performing a "sanity check" on values, and adjust the correspondingly.  Frequency for example:

```
if (frequency < 40.0)
    # Gigahertz
    frequency = frequency * 1E9
else if (frequency < 40000)
    # Megahertz
    frequency = frequency * 1E6
# else Hertz
```

IEEE radio band frequencies (from Wikipedia):

```
S   2 to 4 GHz  Short wave
C   4 to 8 GHz  Compromise between S and X
X   8 to 12 GHz     Used in WW II for fire control, X for cross (as in crosshair). Exotic.
Ku  12 to 18 GHz    Kurz-under
K   18 to 27 GHz    Kurz (German for "short")
Ka  27 to 40 GHz    Kurz-above
```

Comment: letters for frequencies were purposely chosen randomly to confuse enemies. "id" of target is the "universal" NASA id for spacecrafts, here is the  list: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons_batch.cgi?batch=1&COMMAND='*'   Uplegrange and Downlegrange differ if the spacecraft is moving fast; if down < up , s/c is getting closer.

Answer (score 5):

### Follow-up

DSN stores the data internally in a format called "TRK-2-34".  It's described in DSN technical note 820-013.  I've found 15 papers that refer to using this data format.  Two of those papers specifically state that it is an "internal document."  Also consider this blog post:

> This is a technical article about how to use the Deep Space Network (DSN). I’m going to start high briefly and dive in deeply. You can google/wiki the top level stuff. I want to get right into how to translate from DSN formatted data types into range and range rate in kilometers/ kilometers per second.
>
> I want to do this because it was unnecessarily hard for me. Not because of the theory but because of the **lack of documentation or guidance**. I’ve ranted before that the DSN’s idea of a car for sale is a bag of parts, some duplicates, some bad, no instructions.

and

> The documentation on the **TRK-2-34 format is actually comprehensive**, but doesn’t explain how to put the pieces together to get a usable measurement

and

> In general, my #1 complaint with almost everything spacecraft operations related is how needlessly complicated everything is, and **how difficult it is to agree on** data format, interfacing and access, **even units** and modeling.

and

> DSN does a beautiful thing, but they are not a public-facing for-profit company. If you want to use the DSN to track your precious spacecraft, you’ll have to play with the toys they give you. You’ll need a half-decent a priori state vector for your spacecraft, a simulator to propagate it and extract geometry, a binary parser, **the TRK-2-34 handbook**, and all the steps listed above.
>
> https://clarkpatricknewman.wordpress.com/category/nasa/dsn/

The TRK-2-34 format description (820-013) is *not* public information.  It appears the only way you are going to get a copy is to send up your own spacecraft and pay DSN to track it.

Comment: This bodes ill for the chances of [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32329/12102) getting its "authoritative source".  If you like, please feel free to leave a comment or an answer there pointing this out, as you've nicely documented that likelihood here!