# Download all Perseverance Raw Images

Tags: mars, nasa, rovers, imaging, perseverance

I want to make an archive of all the Raw Images Percy will make during her mission. I would love to have separate folders for each Sol. The plan is to run a script which then grabs the images from the Sols I selected. Maybe somebody has something similar running for Curiosity since the Raw Image sites are the same...

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: And what is the question exactly?
If you check server communication when browsing the official site, there is quite clear http request with set of parameters, which is getting back JSON with plenty information including image URLs. Looks simple to use in a script.

Comment: You can use this ext: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-all-images/ifipmflagepipjokmbdecpmjbibjnakm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I decided to get a bit into Python in my holidays and made a script by myself!
I posted it on GitHub, so feel free to use it if you want :)

https://github.com/realcompi/perseverance-raw-images-downloader

Comment: It's great when someone goes and solves their own problem, then takes the time to come back and write about it here! If you are interested in trying similar project, there's the Deep Space Network archive which keeps track of who's talking to who in space. [Understanding the information contained in the Deep Space Network XML data?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32479/12102) came after [Is there any publicly available logging, or “Wayback Machine” for DSN Now activity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17046)